# Unable to get Uint8Array bytes

Tags: javascript

I created an array buffer by

`var uni = new Uint8Array([255, 216, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])`

But when I try to get back the bytes using map

`uni.map(byte => byte.toString(16))`

it returns

`Uint8Array(8) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`

Comment: what is your expected result?

Comment: Avoid working on Uint8Arrays, first convert them to regular arrays, then do whatever you need: `Array.from(uni).map(i => i.toString(16))` - http://jsfiddle.net/4wkLfgsz/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Uint8Array` can only contain 8-bit unsigned integers (integers between 0 and 255). When you use the `Uint8Array.protoype.map()` method, trying to transform each element into a string, they get out of the [0, 255] range and are set to 0.

If you want to transform them into strings, you first transform the `Uint8Array` into a normal `Array` and them use the `Array.prototype.map()`:

```
const array = Array.from(uni)
array.map(byte => byte.toString(16))
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to convert `TypedArray` to `Array` first:
`Array.prototype.slice.call(uni).map(byte=>byte.toString(16))`